# Generar n variables dentro de una función, dado ese n; en R

Tags: base-de-datos, r, funciones

Estimables, tengo una consulta, ¿como se puede hacer en R que a una función le entregue un número n, que esta genere en n variables en su interior y que retorne algún calculo con ellas?, con las que podría hacer cualquier cosa, estoy pensando en que tengo una base de datos y dado un cierto filter o names de este, me genere estas n variables, porque tengo la duda si es que es posible debido a que no se me ocurre otra forma que mediante un proceso recursivo (como en python cuando se trabaja con los merge o el típico ejemplo del cálculo de un factorial); me sirve cualquier idea o código genérico, por favor.

ejemplo:

```
function_n <- function(n,datos){
       x1<-datos$columna_1
       x2<-datos$columna_2
         .
         .
         .
       xn<-datos$columna_n
       lista<-list(x1,x2,...,xn)
       return(lista)
}
```

Quiero generar algo de este estilo, en donde n es la cantidad de columnas con las que quiero trabajar y datos es mi dataframe al que quiero seleccionarle estas columnas, y que funcione para cualquier n menor que la cantidad de columnas del dataframe evidentemente

Comment: amigo, puede refolmular la pregunta o dar algun ejemplo concreto, pues no esta muy claro lo quiere, seria algo asi como generar algunos numeros aleatorios? o ya de una base hecha

Comment: Estimable, ahí puse algo muy genérico de lo que busco

Comment: No sé si esto es lo que buscas, pero la selección de columnas de un `data.frame` puede hacerse entre otras formas, indicando un vector con el número de columna seleccionada, por ejemplo, para seleccionar las primeras 5 columnas: `datos[, c(1,2,3,4,5)]` o bien `n <-5;datos[,1:n]`

Comment: no no, lo que me interesa es que dado un n, la función pueda automaticamente generar esa cantidad de variables internas para trabajar

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A continuacion una funcion que se llama function_n(n, d) donde "n" es la cantidad de columnas que ud va a extraer de la base "d", estas columnas se van a seleccionar de forma aleatoria sin reemplazo dentro de todas las columnas de "d".

```
function_n <- function(n,d){

  if(n <= 0 | n > ncol(d)){
    cat("")
    stop("n debe ser mayor a cero o menor o igual a la cantidad de columnas de la base")
  }else{
    v<-sample(1:ncol(d),n, replace = FALSE)

    m<- matrix(nrow = nrow(d), ncol = n)

    for (i in 1:length(v)) {

      vv<-v[i]  
      m[,i] <-d[,vv]
    }

    lista<-list(m)
    return(c(v,lista))
  }


}

a=matrix(sample(1:100),nrow = 10, ncol = 10)
function_n(3,a)
```

siendo "a"

```
> a
      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10]
 [1,]   28   26   61   78  100   62   11   16   15    43
 [2,]   13   84   65    6   81   92   88   96    2    95
 [3,]   32   40   34    9   41   83   82   69   93    53
 [4,]   79   30   14   75   58   85   70    4   47    52
 [5,]   71   31   67   97   33   44   51   12   55    87
 [6,]   37   46    1   48   18   10   20   27   59    23
 [7,]    5   64   56   17   77   29   60   99   63    50
 [8,]   68    8   76   49   35   57   94   25   19    54
 [9,]   98   80   21   36   89   42   66   91    3    73
[10,]   45    7   39   22   86   24   72   74   38    90
```

Te va a devolver las columnas que fueron seleccionadas y la matriz.

```
[[1]]
[1] 5

[[2]]
[1] 9

[[3]]
[1] 1

[[4]]
      [,1] [,2] [,3]
 [1,]  100   15   28
 [2,]   81    2   13
 [3,]   41   93   32
 [4,]   58   47   79
 [5,]   33   55   71
 [6,]   18   59   37
 [7,]   77   63    5
 [8,]   35   19   68
 [9,]   89    3   98
[10,]   86   38   45
```

y bastaria con hacer

```
function_n(3,a)[[4]]
```

para extraer solo la matriz .

Comment: Ya, bacán, me quedó bien claro con ese ejemplo, muchas gracias!!!

Answer (score 0):

No estoy muy seguro si esto es lo que quieres pero para sustituir la función de ejemplo que has dado se puede hacer como:

```
lista <- as.list(datos[,1:n])
```

Comment: Hola JaiPizGon, deberías añadirn una descripción con lo que hace esa línea de código, dónde iría en el código compartido y cómo/por qué soluciona el problema expuesto. Lee [answer] para más información.